# Auto play flowplayer video when video in viewport

Tags: jquery, html, flowplayer

Is there any known way of auto playing video when video is in viewport, I use the following function to determine when an element is in viewport

```
var isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {
      // get the position of the viewport
      var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  // get the position of the player element
      var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
      var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  // determine if the player element is in fully in the viewport
      return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
        && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/skin/functional.css">

<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/commercial/flowplayer.swf">
   <video>
      <source type="video/mp4"  src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

I tried few samples as explained at https://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html and it doesn't seems to be working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flowplayer(0).play()` in order to play the view.
As for "when it's in view" - you can [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport).

```js
var element         = $(".flowplayer");
var topOfElement    = element.offset().top;
var bottomOfElement = element.offset().top + element.outerHeight(true);
var videoPlayedOnce = false;

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTopPosition   = $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height();
  var windowScrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop()

  if (windowScrollTop > topOfElement && windowScrollTop < bottomOfElement) {
    // Element is partially visible (above viewable area)
    console.log("Element is partially visible (above viewable area)");
  } else if( windowScrollTop > bottomOfElement && windowScrollTop > topOfElement) {
    // Element is hidden (above viewable area)
    console.log("Element is hidden (above viewable area)");
  } else if( scrollTopPosition < topOfElement && scrollTopPosition < bottomOfElement) {
    // Element is hidden (below viewable area)
    console.log("Element is hidden (below viewable area)");
  } else if( scrollTopPosition < bottomOfElement && scrollTopPosition > topOfElement) {
    // Element is partially visible (below viewable area)
    console.log("Element is partially visible (below viewable area)");
  } else {
    // Element is completely visible
    console.log("Element is fully visible");
    if (!videoPlayedOnce) {
      console.log("Only if the video wasn't played already we need to play it");
      flowplayer(0).play()
      videoPlayedOnce = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/skin/functional.css">
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100px; height: 800px;">
  some long div...
</div>
<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="http://releases.flowplayer.org/6.0.5/commercial/flowplayer.swf" style="width: 400px;">
   <video>
<source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm"      type="video/webm" />
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv"       type="video/ogg"  />
   </video>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; width: 100px; height: 800px;">
  some long div...
</div>
```

## Update

Added a variable to check if we already played the video to make sure we don't play it twice (after the user paused it or the video ended already).

Comment: Your solution is perfect only issue I see is it keeps playing video over and again, i do understand this might be additional request but is it possible that video only start playing once ? i.e. when I scroll down video starts playing but if as a user I pause the video  and scroll down and than scroll back up again it doesnt trigger the auto play again ?

Comment: Answer updated to have that as well. Note that I saved the other options in the scroll so you can use them. If the answer is correct please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of modifications should be done to code if one page has multi "flowplayer" videos and all of them needs to be played on scroll position?

Comment: @Timo77, there are several ways to do this. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I made small modifications to previous answer. Now this code loops all flowplayer clases on same page. Every video on page starts automatic. I added pause event too, so there should be only one video at the time playing if not located side by side on page.

```
$('.flowplayer').each(function (i, element) {
    var topOfElement = $(element).offset().top;
    var bottomOfElement = $(element).offset().top + $(element).outerHeight(true);
    var videoPlayedOnce = [];
    videoPlayedOnce[i] = false;

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTopPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var windowScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()

    if (windowScrollTop > topOfElement && windowScrollTop < bottomOfElement) {

    } else if (windowScrollTop > bottomOfElement && windowScrollTop > topOfElement) {

        flowplayer(i).pause()
    } else if (scrollTopPosition < topOfElement && scrollTopPosition < bottomOfElement) {

        flowplayer(i).pause()
    } else if (scrollTopPosition < bottomOfElement && scrollTopPosition > topOfElement) {

    } else {

        if (!videoPlayedOnce[i]) { 
            flowplayer(i).play()
            videoPlayedOnce[i] = true;       
        }
    }
});
});
```